# How to use multi previous step of exogenous variables in VARMAX model

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, arima

I have a multi variables and multi time step prediction problem. Basically, I have a predicted target y, as a time series. And several exogenous variables x. They are also time series data.

I am hoping to use the 4 days lag to predict the future value of y.  So basically is something like following. Please be note I also hope to use the x(t) data for the prediction.

```
y(t)=f(y(t-4), y(t-3), y(t-2), y(t_1), x(t-4), x(t-3), x(t-2), x(t-1), x(t))
```

But it looks like the [VARMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX.html?highlight=varmax#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX) model from statsmodel only considers one time step of x?

Also, how could I predict multi step of y when the x is available? I think I should treat x as an exogenous variable.

Comment: The order is the number of lags.  Order (4,0) will include t-1, ..., t-4 of all variables in the model. You can't include x(t) on the right hand side since this leads to identification problems. If you want to do this you need to look into structural VARs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To use 4 steps lags of y, the p-order should be 4 i.e. `order = (4,0)`
- To use 4 steps lags of the exogenous variables x, you have to create
  all the lagged exogenous variables manually and pass them to the
  `exog=` parameter as one data frame.

Let x be a pandas data frame containing all exogenous variables.
We can create `x_lag` data frame that will be passed to `exog=` parameter using code bellow:

```
x_list = []

for q in range(5):
    x_lagged = x.shift(q).bfill()
    x_list.append(x_lagged)
    
x_lag = pd.concat(x_list,axis=1)
```

Finally, you fit and predict as follow :

```
model = VARMAX(y, order=(4,0), exog=x_lag)
model_fit = model.fit()
# Suppose you have some later observations of the exogenous variables: x_lag_pred
# and you want to forecast 10 steps ahead.
model_fit.forecast(steps=10, exog=x_lag_pred.iloc[:10,:])
```

Comment: Why must the predictors be lagged to the order of p in the model? In e.g. arima doesn't the model automatically handle this?

Comment: It's the endogenous predictors that are lagged automatically by the model. But the exogenous predictors aren't. This is why we need to lag them manually.